# Text size that adjusts for any size class

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I would like to have the text size change like images when using different size classes with auto layout. Thanks!

Comment: This does not work from Interface Builder, you have to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you design for the largest screen, you can use the `Autoshrink` setting on the label to get the text to fit as the label decreases in size, otherwise you would have to do it via code if you want to both stretch and shrink

Answer (score 0):

```
try this 
-(CGSize)heigtForCellwithString:(NSString *)stringValue withFont:(UIFont*)font{
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(250,9999); // Replace 300 with your label width
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: font};
    CGRect rect = [stringValue boundingRectWithSize:constraint options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:attributes context:nil];

    return rect.size;

}
```